# Linux Command Line using for loop and formatting results

Tags: linux, loops, awk, find, md5

How can I use one command line to provide a list of all files between a certain size and then format the file with name, md5 has and the file size.

The example output should be

```
file1.***     MD5 value   size
file2.***     MD5 value   size etc.
```

Ive tried the following but it displays the md5 on a separate line

```
find 'directory' -size +30000c -size -50000c | 
while read filename 
   do ls -l "$filename" | awk '{print $9 "\t" $5}' 
   md5sum "$filename" | awk '{print $1}' 
done
```

It outputs the follow with the MD5 on a seperate line

```
file1.***   size
MD5

file2.***   size
MD5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rhash` for this simple task

```
find dir/ -type f -size +30000c -size -50000c -exec rhash -p "%p %m %s\n" {} \;
```

- `-p` prints in custom format
- `%p` for file path, `%m` for md5sum and `%s` for file size in bytes

Comment: link to man page: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/rhash.1.html

Answer (score 1):

You are very close, just a few fixes needed:

```
#!/bin/bash
find ./path/to/dir -type f -size +30000c -size -50000c -printf '%s %p\n' |
while read -r size filename; do
    md5=$(md5sum "$filename" | awk '{print $1}')
    printf "%-30s %s %10s\n" "$filename" "$md5" "$size"
done
```

To produce something like:

```
./CHECKSUM                     36e371280a17372537a78167ce22b773        30400
./Makefile                     d21464a020be753a9d821cba58f046bc        40000
```

Let's start with the `find`. We can get the filename (path) *and size* directly from `find` via [`-printf` action](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Print-File-Name). The `%p` specifies the full file name (relative path) and `%s` the size of the file. We put `%s` first, so `read` can parse it, in case the filename contains spaces. Also, we're only interested in files, so we'll use the `-type f` filter.

Next, [`read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read) can read multiple fields (separated by `IFS`, which defaults to space, newline and tab). If there are more fields than variables given, the last variable will hold all the remaining fields. Also, we use `-r` to prevent (special) interpretation of escaped characters in input. For each line read (assuming your filenames *do not contain newlines*), we calculate the MD5 sum with the command you already use.

Finally, we use shell's built-in [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-printf) to format and print all the fields. Formatting mini language is similar to C's printf: `%-30s` means left-aligned 30-characters wide string field, for example.

**Bonus points**: handling filenames with newlines. The one character Unix filenames possibly can not contain is the NULL (`\0`) character. Although `bash` is not particularly good at processing binary (non-text) data, we can still do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
find ./path/to/dir -type f -size +30000c -size -50000c -printf '%s %p\0' |
while read -r -d '' size filename; do
    md5=$(md5sum "$filename" | awk '{print $1}')
    display_name=$(echo -n "$filename" | tr '\n' '?')
    printf "%-30s %s %10s\n" "$display_name" "$md5" "$size"
done
```

First, we use `\0` in `-printf` to separate records `find` outputs, with the matching `read -d ''`. To make filenames suitable for printing in one line, we have to replace (but only for display) all newlines `\n` with something like `?`. We can use `tr` for that, combined with `echo -n` (note we can't use a [here-string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) `<<<"$filename"` instead `echo` because [here-string adds a trailing newline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20157/why-does-a-bash-here-string-add-a-trailing-newline-char)).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than piping find to a set of commands, just call those commands directly in find:

```
find /p/a/t/h -size +30000c -size -50000c -exec sh -c '
    printf "%s\t" "$1"; md5sum "$1" | cut -d " " -f 1 | tr -d \\n;
    printf "\t";
    stat -c %s "$1"' _ {} \;
```

Note that `stat` is non-standard, but the above works for debian. You may need `stat -f %z`.  YMMV